Getting price from a trend line using the line.get_price function
Using code to draw a trend line. I request the latest price in the vol_trend_up/down variable and display the received data via plot. However, it is not the last price that is displayed, but the price at which the line appeared
    if ltop > top
        tline := line.new(bar_index - bst[1] - rb, high[bst[1] + rb], bar_index - rb, high[rb], color=dcolor, extend=extend.right)
        t_angle := (high[bst[1] + rb] - high[rb]) / bst[1]
        if t_angle < t_angle[1] and t_angle[1] != 0
            line.set_extend(tline[1], extend=extend.none)
        if t_angle > t_angle[1] and t_angle[1] != 0
            line.set_extend(tline, extend=extend.none)
    if ltop <= top
        t_angle := 0.0
        t_angle
    if chdashed
        line.set_style(tline[1], style=line.style_dashed)
    vol_trend_down := line.get_price(tline, bar_index)

plot(vol_trend_up, "Vol green", color = color.white)


This Trend_line code is publicly available

There is a small error in the text - in the raft the argument is vol_trend_down
